# TinyMCE 3.9.3 adds an un-necessary SPAN when deleting a P

Tags: tinymce

When the following sequence is carried out I end up with spans being automatically added, which change the font size. This is all carried out in normal text mode, not HTML mode.

1/ Editor contains `<p>Test</p>`

2/ Hit return twice and enter some text, editor now contains `<p>Test</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Now</p>`.

3/ Move the cursor up so that its on the empty paragraph and hit delete once. Now the editor contains `<p>Test</p><p><span style="font-size: 0.75em; line-height: 1.7em;">Now</span></p>`.

TinyMCE v 3.9.3

I know its an old version of the editor, so if I have to I will upgrade, but wondering if anyone has any idea why this is happening, and ideally has a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem only on Chrome. Simple solution below but only remove styles not spans

```
editor.on('keyup', function(e) {
  var node = editor.selection.getNode();
  // workaround for chrome to generate style attr when press del
  if (node && e.keyCode === 46) {
    node.removeAttribute('style');
  }
});
```

Comment: Great to hear I'm not alone! What version on TinyMCE are you using? I'm wondering if its actually a bug that should be reported, but I'm not using the latest version.

Comment: I'm using version 2.0. It was fixed in TinyMCE 4.1.1.